# tengo este programa y no me funciona bien creo que el problema son con los if

Tags: python

Este es el enunciado pero los if me dan problemas porque cuando no se cumplen los casos igual da True.

Función EsProteina, que recibe como parámetro el arreglo ListaCodones (creado en
la pregunta anterior) y retorna True o False si la secuencia es o no un gen codificador de
proteínas.
Un gen codificador de proteínas es una cadena que:

a.Comienza con un codón de inicio válido (ATG).

b.Termina con un codón de parada válido (uno de los siguientes: TAA, TAG o TGA)

c. Contiene al menos 5 codones totales (incluido el codón de inicio y el codón final)

d. La citosina (C) y la guanina (G) combinadas representan al menos el 30 % de su masa
total

```
def EsProteina():
    seq= str(input("Ingrese la cadena de valores :"))
    seq= seq.replace("-","")
    seq= seq.upper()
    dentro = ""
    cont= 0
    carac= 3
    separador= " "
    for i in seq:
        if cont == carac:
            dentro += separador
            cont= 0

        cont += 1
        dentro += i
    result= dentro
    result= result.split()

    contA= 0
    contC= 0
    contG= 0
    contT= 0
    respuesta= True
    for e in seq:
        if e== "A":
            contA += 1
        if e== "C":
            contC += 1
        if e== "G":
            contG += 1
        if e== "T":
            contT += 1
    total= contA + contC + contG + contT
    porcentaje= 100(contC/total) + 100(contG/total)
    if seq[0:3] == "ATG":
        if seq[-3:len(seq)] == "TAA" or "TAG" or "TGA":
            if total >= 15:
                if porcentaje >= 30:
                    respuesta= True
    else:
        respuesta= False
    final= print("Lista de codones :",result, "\n ¿Es proteina? :", respuesta)
    return final
```

Comment: Lee [ask]: Tanto en la pregunta anterior, como en esta, no has puesto títulos descriptivos. Procura ir _directo al grano_, "creo que...", "no funciona bien..." no nos dan indicios del problema en cuestión.

Comment: La función `esProteina` no recibe ningun parámetro, para empezar ...

Comment: Mostrar datos de entradas con sus correspondientes resultados también ayudaría.

Comment: hola lo siento es que no se porque algunos casos como si no  cumple la b la de termina con TAA,TAG o TGA y termina con otro igual me da true

Comment: Entonces, una sugerencia de título: _Cualquiera sea la condición, los if siempre devuelven True_ (nada más como ejemplo).

Comment: vale muchas gracias es que soy nuevo

Answer (score 0):

No sé por que complicas tanto el problema, sencillamente puedes hacer tu código en base de `if` según las condiciones que te dan, de esa forma lo hice yop. Lo único que no entendí muy bien es el punto *c*, pues no se si la proteína siempre va tener grupos de 3 o puede tener más, en el caso de que cada grupo sea de 3 *letras* la longitud mínima de la proteína (en forma de cadena) será `15` (5 codones de 3 *letras*).

Para el punto *a* simplemente tenemos que escoger los 3 primeros elementos de la proteína (cadena sin espacios ni caracteres especiales) eso lo hacemos con *slices* `str[:3]`

Para el punto *b* será al revés, en lugar de verificar los 3 primeros lo hacemos con los 3 últimos, también lo hacemos con *slices* pero con índices negativos para empezar desde atrás `str[-3:]` (desde la posición `-3` hasta el final `:`). En tu caso haces mal la comparación en `if seq[-3:len(seq)] == "TAA" or "TAG" or "TGA":` esto solo evaluará `if seq[-3:len(seq)] == "TAA"` y luego simplemente evalúa si `"TAG"` es `True`(que si lo es) y luego `"TGA"` si es `True` (que también lo es) por lo que tu resultado será `True` si la cadena **no termina** en `"TAA"`.

Para punto *c* solo evaluamos que la longitud de nuestra proteína sea mayor o igual a 15 (en caso mi suposición de antes sea cierta)

Para el punto *d* simplemente tenemos que contar las veces que aparece la combinación `C` y `G` (tanto `CG` como `GC`), para eso nos apoyamos del método `count()`

```py
def esProteina():
    cadena_proteina = input("ingrese la cadena: ").upper().replace("-","") #ATGcggcgtcgaTAG
    if cadena_proteina[:3] != "ATG": #comprobamos que empiece con ATG
        return "Cadena no valida"
    elif cadena_proteina[-3:] not in ["TAA","TAG","TGA"]: #comprobamos la terminacion
        return "cadena no valida"
    elif len(cadena_proteina) <= 15: #verificamos la longitud
        return "cadena no valida"

    percent = cadena_proteina.count("CG")+cadena_proteina.count("GC") #contamos
    if (len(cadena_proteina)*30)/100 > percent: #sacamos el procentaje y evaluamos
        print("percent:",percent)
        return "Cadena no valida"
    #en caso haya pasado a todos los if significa que si es una proteina
    return "es una proteina"
```

**probamos**

```py
print(esProteina())
```

**resultado**

```
ingrese la cadena: ATGcggcggcgcTAG
ATGCGGCGGCGCTAG
es una proteina
```

Como sugerencia, es bueno colocar un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y salida esperada. Hice la respuesta basándome en las condiciones que das para saber si es proteína o no, por lo que cualquier otro código también debería de tomar en cuenta eso, por tal razón hice la respuesta, de lo contrario hubiera sido adivinando.